# Include Specific list in PnP Provisioning

Tags: spfx, office-365-developer, pnp-provision, office-dev-pnp

I would like to use PnP Provisioning engine to clone list from one site to another.

In order to do so, I would like to create provisioning template with just one list in it.

When I use GetProvisioningTemplate with below code, it takes all list from source site but I would like to create a template with just one specific list.

```
ProvisioningTemplateCreationInformation ptci = new ProvisioningTemplateCreationInformation(web);
ptci.BaseTemplate = null;
ptci.HandlersToProcess = Handlers.Lists;

var provisioningTemplate = web.GetProvisioningTemplate(ptci);
```

Comment: I'm after the same question. Does anyone have an idea how to do this even if its possible via powershell?

Comment: I end up creating a template with all list and then removed all list except the one I am interested in.

Comment: Nice one...was thinking of that too myself

Comment: Can we do same including list items? This example migrates only definitions but nit (list)items..

Comment: I know this is an old question but you can configure PnP provisioning via JSON to limit the provisioning to specific lists - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/configuring-the-pnp-provisioning-engine